# Difficulty in finding right values for dhyper function

Tags: r, statistics

We have this situation:

*6 doctors and 19 nurses attend a conference*

*all 25 names are put in a hat and randomly selected without replacement*

*What is the probability that 1 nurse and 4 doctors are picked (P(nurses=1 and doctors=4)?*

Can any of you shed some light on how we would use the `dhyper()` function in R to solve this?

Comment: I have looked at the documentation, but it is unclear to me which values goes where in the parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've copied the description of the [hypergeometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution) from Wikipedia, replacing the parameters with the names of the arguments from `dhyper`. Hopefully this gets you most of the way there:

> the probability of **x** successes (random draws for which the object drawn has a specified feature) in **k** draws, without replacement, from a finite population of size **m + n** that contains exactly **m** objects with that feature, wherein each draw is either a success or a failure.